# Is it smart to replace ICollection with ObservableCollection<T> wpf ef

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, observablecollection, icollection

I'm a beginner with wpf app building and entity framework.
I'm building my first wpf app, I found out I should have replaced my auto-generated `ICollection` with `ObservableCollection`.
The problem is that I already did most of my code so far but am having some issues with `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I see all the codes about `INotifyPropertyChanged` use `ObservableCollection`.

Is it bad if I go to my auto-generated code now and replace the `ICollection` with `ObservableCollection`? Will it mess up my app?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[`ObservableCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) is only useful if you want to add items to a collection at some point, and have a UI control automatically update to display the added / deleted items. ObservableCollection also has potential threading issues - any change to the collection must be done on the same thread as it was created on.

It has nothing to do with reflecting changes to properties of individual elements within the collection - that is what [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8) is for.

Comment: Thank you! I am building a CRUD app so i will be constantly updating inserting and deleting items. My issue is i see lots of people used ObservableCollection and now i dont know if its safe to change my iCollection to ObservableCollection. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: This is why you shouldn't just blindly copy code you find online. Take time to study each class used and what functionality it provides - does it actually match with the problem you're trying to solve.